# 64-bit binary and iOS 6 support

Tags: ios, ios7

In September Apple stated [this](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=9162013a) in an announcement to devs. Since then there are no news for the ability to build for both 32-bit and 64-bit and maintaining also support for iOS 6. Is this possible or by upgrading your project settings to 64-bit the minimum iOS version supported is 7 even if you specify 6 in the project settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build both 32 and 64 bit libraries for at least iOS 6, Apple stated this after a ~month after that (and I've tried this personally). Just set `armv7, armv7s, arm64` as architectures and iOS 6.0 as deployment target.

Do you have a problem with that?

Comment: Seems to work. Haven't build for release but seems ok. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug in early Xcode 5. This has since been fixed. In order to add 64-bit binary support, you need to add `arm64` to your target architectures.